# Hola, ¿Cómo puedo ingresar una función por teclado en Matlab?

Tags: matlab

¿Cómo puedo ingresar una función por teclado en Matlab?. Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buenos días, lo que quiero es  que el programa le pida al usuario ingresar una f(x) ,como por ejemplo f(x)=2x+1; parecido a lo que hace "input" para una variable sencilla. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a una función anónima, para el ejemplo que pones de:

```
f(x) = 2x + 1
```

Podrías redactarla en tu script como:

```
y = @(x) 2*x + 1;
```

Aquí te dejo la explicación de la [documentación oficial](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)